# How can I add screen reader to my React JS website?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, highlight, screen-readers

Assume that I have some paragraphs, lists, image alt text, etc. And also I have a button (play button) on top Navigation bar of my website.
So when a user clicks on that button, I want to narrate the content of my website to the user one by one. And also I want to highlight the text.
Is this possible in React Js? If possible please tell me how can I achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: this is much too broad a question, particularly with no code provided. But as for "is it possible in React", this is the wrong way to look at things. Making a website accessible to screenreaders is mostly (Javascript can come into it too, particularly with regards to keyboard navigation) about using the correct HTML - using elements with the correct semantic meaning, enhanced with ARIA attributes where needed (but many developers overdo this). There's no reason you can't do this with React since ultimately you're in control of what HTML is rendered via JSX.

Comment: The question shows a very common misunderstanding of accessibility. Rendering a site more accessible means rendering it more compatible with assistive technology (AT), as Robin said “accessible to” AT. That is software and devices that people with disabilities already use and expect to work. That includes way more than just screen readers. Following the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/) makes sure of that. So again, you need to make sure your code is accessible *to* screen readers, not implement a screen reader.